# Firebase remote config instant localization after language change on app

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase-remote-config

is there a way to instantly reload `FirebaseRemoteConfig` cache after app locale changed on app?

It is working as expected while using development mode because `minimumFetchIntervalInSeconds` is set `0` so basically it does not store cache at all.

But when comes to production version it does need to wait while `FirebaseRemoteConfig` cache fetch interval ends.

For localization I am using: USER_PROPERTY -> LANGUAGE_CODE which is set after user changes language on app.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to force a request to the server for a single request, you can use this API which lets you override the minimumFetchInterval (example in Swift):

```
remoteConfig.fetch(withExpirationDuration: TimeInterval(0)) { (status, error) -> Void in
  ...
}
```

Be sure to only use this in a part of your app that happens infrequently, otherwise you may get temporarily throttled.

Comment: I am using similar strategy, except doing `remoteConfig.reset()` and then doing re fetch. But I don't think that is the best practice, what if user changes language on app 10 times an hour? Of course it is not common case, but....

Answer (score 0):

After investigation figured out that firebase downloads all configs no matter what are conditions and keeps it inside the app so no refetching is needed after user properties or other properties are changing.

What is needed to reactivate parameters to check if conditions are matching them, it can be done with:

```
remoteConfig.activate()
```

More info [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/remoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfig.html#public-taskboolean-activate)